# Invalid 'Podfile' file syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting '}'

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

**I am trying to install a pod in project. But i am getting this error:**

> Invalid 'Podfile' file syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting
>   '}'.

**Podfile contains:**

```
platform :ios, '7.0' pod 'RestKit', '0.21.0'
```

**The terminal shows following message:**

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: compile error
/Users/work/Desktop/tg/RESTKitDemo/Podfile:1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting '}'
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265
^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.

#  from /Users/work/Desktop/tg/RESTKitDemo/Podfile:1
#  -------------------------------------------
>  {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265
#  {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
#  -------------------------------------------
```

Can i know what is the problem with my podfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you correctly copied your Podfile over there needs to be a newline between those two lines.

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'RestKit', '0.21.0'
```

Also as of a relatively new version of CocoaPods you actually don't need that first line, the command line tool will determine the correct OS based off of your project's settings.

Edit:

From the new output you posted it looks like your `Podfile` isn't actually a plain text file. You should recreate it in an editor like Sublime Text and make sure it saves as a plain text file.

Comment: From the new output you posted it looks like your Podfile isn't actually a plain text file. You should recreate it in an editor like Sublime Text

Comment: @Keith, your mention about deleting the first line was very helpful today. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I got error

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
```

becasue I was declaring Pod files like

```
pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift',
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

there is one "," (comma mark) in above podfile name  **pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift',**. I just removed the colon mark.
It worked.

correct way:

```
pod 'SlideMenuControllerSwift'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

Comment: same was the case with me , i has accidently added an extra alphabet after declaring the pod.

Comment: Comma, not colon

Answer (score 1):

I was faced same problem when, I changed my MAC.

1- Make setup - [Pod setup or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-to-install-cocoapods)

So I created a new test project --
And open `terminal` 
Run these command

```
cd /path your project
pod init
// add any pod in your pod file 
pod install
```

and then you can `update pod` in your old project .

Answer (score 0):

No special characters or any thing else is allowed in pod file, except the name of pod which we are integrating, unknowingly if we enter any characters such as , \ etc. it may result in the following error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue because I was doing:

```
pod 'Fireworks', :path '/Users/honey/Documents/mypod-ios'
```

The fix was to just add: `=>`

```
pod 'Fireworks', :path => '/Users/honey/Documents/mypod-ios'
```